# Unit weighting for linear composites / regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, cohens-d

[Cohen (1990)](https://www.uvm.edu/~bbeckage/Teaching/DataAnalysis/AssignedPapers/Cohen_1990.pdf) mentions a regression that I have not heard about before. Here is how I understand his description:

- Standardize the dependent and the independent variables
- Regress the standardized dependent variable on the standardized independent variables
- Replace the regression coefficients as follows. Those that are positive (and statistically significant?), replace with +1; those that are negative (and statistically significant?), replace with -1; those that are not statistically significant, replace with 0.

Where can I learn more about this regression? What is it called? Is it used in publications? Is there a good modern discussion of it? How do you decide when to replace a coefficient with 0 (is it statistical significance or something else)?